# emmeans error: Error in match.arg(type) : 'arg' should be one of “link”, “response”, “terms”

Tags: r, emmeans, gamlss

I'm trying to calculate estimated marginal means with the `emmeans` library for a `gamlss` object. My `gamlss` object comes from a zero inflated beta regression. Let's say that my model is called m1 and one of my variables is `internationaltreaty`, so I call:

`emmeans(m1,"internationaltreaty",type="response")`

and I get the following error message:

```
Error in match.arg(type) : 
  'arg' should be one of “link”, “response”, “terms”
```

If I use a different model object (for example glm), emmeans works with this code. To me it seems like that emmeans doesn't recognize my type argument. Has anyone experienced something similar?

Thanks.

Comment: You could try the [ggeffects-package](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/), which should support gamlss-models.

Comment: Thanks! I eventually used ggpredict.

Answer (score 0):

That error does not come from trying to match your `type` argument. I can tell this because `type = “terms”` is not a possibility in `emmeans`. So I wonder if you get the same error even without the `type` argument.

Support for `gamlss` objects in **emmeans** is pretty sketchy, and I think that this is just a model that doesn’t work. You might be able to work around it using the `qdrg` function.

Comment: I ran into the same error with a gamlss model and this error shows up with and without type="response"